# Android: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I am trying to build a simple three (3) tabs app. I am supposed to be implementing three public methods of ActionBar.TabListener.
I believe that is exactly what I am doing in the below code. The compiler however believes that I do not. All three come with the error: "method does not override or implement a method from supertype" 
I checked methods' signatures, do not even know where to look, now.
Please advise.

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;


public class InSync extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Backup", "Restore", "Settings"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_in_sync);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please post the error from the logcat.

Comment: Probably need to change your imports to reference the support actionbar but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods you try to implement are

```
void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)

void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
```

and

```
void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
```

I guess the `Tab` class you are using is not the "right" `Tab` class.

EDIT:

On [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html) link you can see that there is a certain `android.app.FragmentTransaction`. However, you have imported `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction`. Isn't it possible that this is the problem, as the links to `FragmentTransaction` from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.TabListener.html) point to the page of `android.app.FragmentTransaction`. I believe you should have this code:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;


public class InSync extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Backup", "Restore", "Settings"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_in_sync);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

and if it works you can test even without namespaces.

Comment: You are right. Changing android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction for android.app.FragmentTransaction solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you messed up with support libraries. Try

```
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

instead of

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

**Upd.**
Or better use only support libraries:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;
```